# Unable to see Add Schedule button on Jasper Server 6.2.1

Tags: scheduling, jasperserver

I am unable to see 'Add Schedule' button on jasper server 6.2.1 for old or new reports. 
Earlier, on right clicking a report and choosing schedule option, opened a page that lists the scheduled jobs for the selected report. This page also had a 'Add Schedule' button to create a new schedule. 
Now this button is not visible. I am logged in from superuser.

Comment: Which list do you use where you right click? Only the list "Reports" provides this functionality.

Comment: After login, view -> repository, then selecting reports under the organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Administrative view**

When using login, view -> repository, selecting reports under organization:

This is the repository where you set user rights or change settings in the report. No possibility to change schedules (at least in v6.2.1).

**Schedule view**

In the "library" or when selecting "reports" after logging in on your dashboard you are able to change the schedule.

NOTE: *This differs because a user might have rights to change schedules, but not to change report settings.*